# Problem getting in adjust the image in drawable canvas

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on the game which i develop on android and i am just stuck on adjust the images. I want the spinning ball image in center where i targeted the red color on the given image and the both bottom left and right player images on yellow mark on the given images.

Here is the some code i used for dice and the player :-

Dice :-

```
dice.get(0).setPosition((gWidth + dice.get(0).getWidth()) / 300,
                    (gHeight + dice.get(0).getHeight()))
```

Player 1 and player 2 :-

```
male = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.male);
    canvas.drawBitmap(male, 0, canvas.getHeight() - male.getHeight(), null);
    female = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.female);
    canvas.drawBitmap(female, canvas.getWidth() - female.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() - female.getHeight(), paint);
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Are you unsure on how to place the images there? I don't see why moving the images is any difficult since you already know how to render them at a specific location.

Comment: I want the spinning ball in red mark position in the center but i don't know how to do? i try each n every numbers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing the ball in the middle should be pretty straight-forward. The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
// Center of your screen
float positionX = (canvas.getWidth() - ball.getWidth()) / 2f; 
// 28% above the bottom of your screen. Should be almost correct.
// Change to whatever number works.
float positionY = canvas.getHeight() * 0.72f - ball.getHeight();
ball.setPosition(positionX, positionY);
```

That should place the ball in the middle and a bit above the bottom of your screen.

When placing the player images you just have to offset their x-position by their width. Something like this:

```
// All the way to the left
float maleX = 0;
// Same height as the ball
float maleY = canvas.getHeight() * 0.72f - male.getHeight();

// Offset by male width to place next to male
float femaleX = male.getWidth();
// Same height as male and ball
float femaleY = canvas.getHeight() * 0.72f - female.getHeight();

// Draw male and female
canvas.drawBitmap(male, maleX, maleY, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(female, femaleX, femaleY, null);
```

These code snippets are of course just pseudo code and you will have to manually change some numbers so that they work. I've also assumed a top-down y-coordinate system where the origin in the top left corner and the origin of the images is the bottom left corner because it seems like this is the case from your examples.

Comment: when i touch on screen my ball has been display and roll but i want when i touch the ball its spin and give me the random number

Comment: @KunalPitale You should post that as a different question.

Comment: Your code is work now thanks @Charanor, If i want to ask different question so should i edit this question ??

Comment: @KunalPitale No, post a completely new question using the red [Ask Question] button on the top right.